# Fetch first and last name

Tags: php, html

In my database I have  a column "first_name" and "last_name" (there is more in there but not related to my question)

Here is the code :

```
//Get variables for email
    $qry_get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = $id");
        while($row_get = mysql_fetch_array($qry_get))
            {
                $id = $row_get['id'];
                $name = $row_get['first_name'];
                $email = $row_get['email'];
                $password = $row_get['password'];
        }
```

And this works fine. But im trying to get $name to fetch both first_name and last_name. Is it possible?

It is so when the details are inserted into the database it will show both names rather than just the first name.

I have tried to do it like

```
//Get variables for email
    $qry_get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = $id");
        while($row_get = mysql_fetch_array($qry_get))
            {
                $id = $row_get['id'];
                $name = $row_get['first_name'],['last_name'];
                $email = $row_get['email'];
                $password = $row_get['password'];
        }
```

But it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get two values at once like you did, you have to concatenate the value of `$row_get['first_name']` and the value of `$row_get['last_name']` :

```
//Get variables for email
$qry_get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = $id");
    while($row_get = mysql_fetch_array($qry_get))
        {
            $id = $row_get['id'];
            $name = $row_get['first_name'] . ' ' .$row_get['last_name'];
            $email = $row_get['email'];
            $password = $row_get['password'];
    }
```

Comment: Glad it helped you, feel free to accept the answer ;)

Comment: I know this is unrelated to the question but how would i get the link to open on a new page? I know its target=_blank but where does it go?   <tr align=\"center\">
<td>Date</td>
<td>Event</td>
<td></td>
</tr>";

while($results_row = mysql_fetch_array($results))

{
echo "<tr align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"" .$rowbgcolor. "\">";
echo "<td>" . $results_row['date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $results_row['event'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href=\"" . $results_row['link'] . "\">Link</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
?>  its for the $link field.

Comment: It goes as an attribute to the <a> tag :  echo "<td><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"" . $results_row['link'] . "\">Link</a></td>";

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use SQL, it's open to attack and is deprecated, Look into SQLi or PHP PDO data objects. Why are you selecting  all in your query when you only need 2 fields ? I will work with your code though

```
SELECT first_name,last_name FROM members WHERE id = $id"
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for you reply. I am fetching all due to fetching more than just first and last name. this was the bit I was stuck on thats all. Also I will look into the sqli as you said thanks..